# Error installing rails (no write Permissions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

When attempting to install rails, I get the following:

```
$ gem install ruby
Fetching: ruby-0.1.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

I installed ruby 1.9.3 with rbenv and set it to the global version:

```
rbenv global 1.9.3-p448
```

So I'm not sure why it's trying to access the system version...?

Comment: I'd recommend using https://rvm.io/ for managing a separate Ruby version.

Comment: if you run `which ruby` what do you get?

Comment: I get 1.8, the pre-installed system version

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by adding the following to .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Also, this line is needed too (though it was already there):

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

For info on modifying bash_profile, see:

http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac